# Samsung Front Load Gas Dryer, plastic connection problem

Tags: dryer, gas, crack, plastic, fitting

RE: Samsung Front Load Gas Dryer. DV42H5200GW. T
his should have been an easy install, but **plastic gas fitting seems to have cracked**. I was just connecting my existing gas line to the dryer, and I may have over tightened the fitting as I heard a slight crack or squeak and now the plastic fitting on dryer is turning as I turn the line fitting. I will now remove the back panel to investigate, but I cannot afford to hire a pro.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the plastic part is intended to spin like a female garden hose end does. To check for leaks, drizzle soapy water over the connection. Without photos or a better description of the problem I can't say much more.

Comment: Sorry, I meant water line - this is a gas dryer with a steam option. So this is the water fitting that has broken.

Comment: Please edit your post to correct that.